# Ignore quotation when reading input

Tags: c, input

Is there any way to read input in this format:

```
{int,"string1","string2","string3"}
```

Obviously the printf/scanf functions do not let me ignore quotations so I was wondering how I can bypass this limitation. One way I was thinking was using strtok and ignoring the "{", commas and quotes. Any faster way I may not know of?

Comment: Yes.  Look up scan sets in your `scanf()` manual page.

Comment: Are they really curly quotes in the input?

Comment: No they are not curly. Just regular quotes like the ones used in printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely ignore any characters:

```
char buf[100];
scanf("%99[^{},\"]", buf);
```

This will read into `buf` the first token, in your case `int`. Repeat this call for all tokens you need.

Comment: Thank you. The answer was indeed Scansets as pointed by @Jonathan Leffler